# cast XPath Expression to Boolean in Apache Camel

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I have xml with flag:`<ns4:flag>false</ns4:flag>`. And I want to read this flag and set it's value to FLAG property:

```
.setProperty( FLAG, xpath("//*[local-name()='flag']/text()", Boolean.class))
```

Using code above I get 'true' value instead of 'false'. Also tried `resultType(Boolean.class)` and `boolean()` xpath function inside expression, but it didn't work out. Any ideas how can I do this cast?

Comment: What version of XPath are you using? What exactly do you have to give to `.setProperty` as an argument so that it will set the property to false? Is the last argument (`Boolean.class`) necessary?

Comment: what version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Please post the entire XML message. Is it possible that it has more than one `flag` element?

Comment: I use XPath v1.0, Camel v2.12.0.redhat-610379. There is only one flag element in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath, the following expression will return boolean value `true` when the text content equals string value `"true"`, and return boolean value `false` otherwise :

```
//*[local-name()='flag']/text() = 'true'
```

**<kbd>[`xpathteseter.com demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8535fb1ef54339f999fd45d42a3b9504)</kbd>**

So I guess, changing your XPath expression to the above XPath would work.

Comment: didn't know that xml boolean is case sensitive, thanks

Comment: And seems like boolean() call is unnecessary, in Camel at least

Comment: @divideByZero very likely so, because that is also the case in XPath. I was just being extra careful since I have no experience using Camel. So does the above XPath actually work for you in Camel without `boolean()`?

Comment: yes, and as far as I see, it works on xpathtester.com without boolean() call, '=' operator already returns boolean. Edited